# Distribution of function of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

If $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, how would I go about finding the CDF of
 $Y=(X-X^2)^2$ ?Thanks.

Comment: You can use the [transformation method](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html).

Comment: Any affort so far?

Comment: I found the distribution function of Z=X^2 to be sqrt(z) for 0<z<1, but I'm stuck on where to go from here. The only thing we've been taught in class is how to do the one-to-one inverse function method so I can only use that for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sketch of $y=(x-x^2)^2$ will reveal that if $X\in (0;1)$ then $Y\in (0;0.0625]$, and that the section $0\leq Y\leq y$ will correspond to two intervals on the support of $X$.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y\leq y) & =\mathsf P(0\leq (X-X^2)^2\leq y) & :\text{for } y\in(0;1/16]
\\ & = \mathsf P\left(\left\{0\leq X\leq \Box\right\}\cup \left\{\Box\leq X\leq 1\right\}\right)
\end{align}$

Can you determine what these boxes contain?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I worked out the empty boxes to be 
(1-sqrt(1-4*sqrt(y)))/2 and (1+sqrt(1-4*sqrt(y)))/2.

 I worked this out by finding the intersection of the curves (x-x^2) and sqrt(y). Is this correct? Or is there a more formal approach to find the intervals?

Comment: That's it exactly, @student2468 .  The next step is to use the fact that $X$ is uniformly distributed to evaluate the probability.